# Needs to find line pattern in another file and get the sum of corresponding value in particular column using python

Tags: python, shell

I have 2 files where file 1 has the below lines and file 2 has the following lines with some million records. Now I want to search file 1 entries in file 2 and generate the report with sum of 2nd column and the corresponding line next to each other in new file.

File 1 entries:

```
/dataset1
/dataset2
```

File 2 entries:

```
12 5 /opt/dataset1
 6 0 /opt/dataset2
 5 8 /dataset1
```

Looking for  sum of 2nd column values with pattern next to each other

```
13 /dataset1
 0 /datase2
```

thank you
CS

Answer (score 0):

I would first process File 1 and create a regex with the following format:

```
\d\s+(\d)\s+\S*(\/dataset1|\/dataset2)
```

After creating the regex, just use `re.findall` to find all the relevant information, and sum all the matches. It should be easy...

Of course, the regex doesn't have a fixed format, you would need to generate it according to the lines of the first file. Something like that:

```
def generate_regex(file1_lines):
    regex = "\d\s+(\d)\s+\S*("
    for line in file1_lines:
        line = line.replace(r"/", r"\/")
        regex += line.strip() + "|"
    regex = regex[:-1] + ")"
    return regex
```